# How to dynamically create nested elements with varying instances of child elements in JQuery? Do I use a loop or is there a more efficient way?

Tags: jquery, css-grid

I am only familiar with a single way to create dynamic elements, shown below,
`$('#id).append($('<div/>').addClass('level2').append($('div/').addClass('level3')))`

So, what do you do when you need to create multiple instances of elements you're appending? That I am aware of so far, I can't break in that statement to define a quantity to create or place a loop in it. I tried using loops the same way I would with pure JS but it's a total mess, I know there has to be a much easier way to do it. I created a JSFiddle with a simplified version of what I am needing. I defined values and used for loops in the example just for demonstrations purposes. On my live site the variables used are defined by a combination of data from an array of objects and manipulated by user input.

[JSFiddle NestedElements](https://jsfiddle.net/Ayalayvonne30/c7do6xm5/143/)

Comment: No matter what there is going to be some messy loops. I might use a templating utility, like [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) to do this. For me, it makes the reading a little bit easier. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/bxrkdzqp/